# Can Biopython parse Derwent GENESEQ format?

Tags: biopython

I'm trying to parse files from the Derwent GENESEQ database.

The files are supposedly in EMBL formatted, but there are small differences that break `SeqIO.parse('foo.dat', 'embl')`. Has anyone successfully parsed these files with Biopython or other Python libs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up subclassing the Biopython EMBL parser and hacking up my own GENESEQ parser.